# How to UNION/LEFT JOIN/INNER JOIN results from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and CROSS APPLY TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to merge 2 results from different query, the first query is from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and the second query is from `usermasterfile`, I tried `UNION, UNION ALL, LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN` it into my `CROSS APPLY` table, but no luck. Is there a way to do this without following conditional statements between 2 tables? Just simply put the 2 results ***side-by-side***?

I just can't see any way to merge it? both of the query does not have any similar value to be used as a parameter to avoid duplication.

This is my `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
SELECT 
     column_name 
FROM
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'usermasterfile'
```

Thi is my `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT  
     dbTbl.usermasterfile
FROM  
     usermasterfile mTbl
CROSS APPLY 
     (VALUES
     (mTbl.username),
     (CAST(mTbl.password AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.passwordsha1)),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.employeeidno))
     ) 
dbTbl (usermasterfile)
WHERE 
     mTbl.employeeidno = 'D0420000002'
```

This is what I got so far, I don't know what condition to use since I do not have any parameter to use for the both table.

```
SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.usermasterfile), 
     t1.usermasterfile, 
     t2.column_name 
FROM
(SELECT  
     dbTbl.usermasterfile
FROM  
     usermasterfile mTbl
CROSS APPLY 
     (VALUES
     (mTbl.username),
     (CAST(mTbl.password AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.passwordsha1)),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.employeeidno))
     ) 
dbTbl (usermasterfile)
WHERE 
     mTbl.employeeidno = 'D0420000002') AS T1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
     column_name 
FROM
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'usermasterfile' ) AS T2
     ON T1.usermasterfile IS NOT NULL
     AND T2.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

> I used `ON T1.usermasterfile IS NOT NULL` AND `T2.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL` just to trigger it, unfortunately there are rows that are NULL, and must remain NULL.

Is there a way for this? or any option? I tried combining both table via `LEFT JOIN`, unfortunately it does not work because the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` data is displayed vertically, and the table `usermasterfile mTbl` result is displayed horizontally.

I tried combining them directly via `CROSS APPLY`, but I have no way to stop `dbTbl.usermasterfile` from duplicating it's values.

```
SELECT 
     column_name, 
     dbTbl.usermasterfile
FROM
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS , 
     usermasterfile mTbl 
CROSS APPLY 
     (VALUES
     (mTbl.username),
     (CAST(mTbl.password AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.passwordsha1)),
     (ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.employeeidno))) 
dbTbl (usermasterfile)
WHERE 
     mTbl.employeeidno = 'D0420000002'
AND 
     TABLE_NAME = 'usermasterfile'
```

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this will give you the results you want if you are just looking to create a list of column names and values.  I am not sure why you need to JOIN to another table to get the column names when you already are using them to build your row values in the CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT  
     dbTbl.Column_name,dbTbl.usermasterfile
FROM  
     usermasterfile mTbl
CROSS APPLY 
     (VALUES
     ('username',mTbl.username),
     ('password',CAST(mTbl.password AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
     ('passwordsha1',ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.passwordsha1)),
     ('employeeidno',ISNULL(NULL,mTbl.employeeidno))
     ) 
dbTbl (Column_name,usermasterfile)
WHERE 
     mTbl.employeeidno = 'D0420000002'
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I'm looking for. I need to study more on CROSS APPLY.